# in swing, layout components that has different heights

Tags: java, swing, layout, miglayout

We have components that have different heights, we want to show them in a way that vertically  there is as little space as possible (as shown in the picture), how can we do that using miglayout?

[image: components to be oriented]

Comment: that's wraped into JScrollPane?, or Component's Dimension depends of available/free space in JPanel?

Comment: Yes it is placed in a JScrollPane

Comment: Not that there is anything wrong with miglayout, but why does the solution have to use miglayout?

Comment: We can use other alternatives, we just weren't able to do it with miglayout

Comment: BoxLayout: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: @engin `Yes it is placed in a JScrollPane` and Component would be resiziable on Container's resize or not?

Comment: @mKorbel no it is not resizable

Comment: @engin, I suggest you read more about [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: You could write your own layout manager, which is one of the topics under the link that @Moonbeam suggested. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/custom.html On initial glance, BoxLayout may also work.

Comment: @normalocity I would actually  use null layout and calculate the appropriate positions, but before doing it this way I thought asking would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used MigLayout quite a bit, I'm not sure there's a really nice way to do this. What you really want is to have 5 columns and use split on the y axis which you can't do unfortunately.

I see three approaches:

1) Use 5 jpanels, one for each column and just use flowy in MigLayout for each column

2) Setup a matrix and assign each component to a number of cells

```
p.add(component1, "cell 0 0 1 1");
p.add(component2, "cell 1 0 1 2");
```

etc.. This works if pretty well if you don't have a lot of different end points in each column

"span" might be a little cleaner here:

```
p.add(component1, "spany 1");
p.add(component2, "spany 2");
p.add(component3, "spany 1");
p.add(component4, "spany 3");
p.add(component5, "spany 1, wrap");
```

3) Use "nogrid" and just set size bounds on each component

Comment: thx I will use it, we can also do p.add(component1, "wrap"); I guess